# Khan Academy Topic Tree Not Working -Objective C and AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: objective-c, json, api, afnetworking-2, khan-academy

I am attempting to call the khan academy api inside my iOS app.  I am using the AFNetworking class to make the api call.  Here is my code:

```
           AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:@"http://www.khanacademy.org//api/v1/topictree" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSLog(@"no error");
    for (NSString *key in [responseObject allKeys]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [responseObject objectForKey:key]);
    }


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error");
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSLog(@"Error Khan: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

When I visited http://www.khanacademy.org//api/v1/topictree it was a very long list.  I have a hunch it may be the JSON parsing because I am only getting one NSDictionary.  As you can see in the code above I used Fast Enumeration to view the values and the keys.

If that is the correct parse. I have no idea which keys to use to get a list of all the topics. Then when a user clicks on the topic I want to show a list of the video then I need to access the video download url specific to mp4.  I could do it in the playlist list method however it has been deprecated.

The goal of this is to be able to view a list if topics followed by the topics videos followed by the video description then its downloadable url in mp4 format.

I have also been getting the error Error Khan:

The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)

But some of the time it works.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Joel

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Have you looked their api explorer?  My only option now is to manually read the file and create an enumerated list which kind of defeats the purpose.  Were you able to get beyond this issue?

Answer (score 0):

that error code means `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.`

because response json from server is not a valid json for retireve array or object. Try using

```
NSJSONReadingAllowFragments

NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];


NSLog(@"response: %@ error: %@", json, error);
```